# Nuxt application with Tailwind doesn't apply any style in production while working fine in development

Tags: javascript, css, deployment, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a headless application using Nuxtjs and TailwindCss for the front end. Locally the styling is applied normally but once deployed on production, I can see tailwind classes in the html but no CSS is applied/generated. Here are is my config.
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --port=$PORT",
    "build": "~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build",
    "start": "~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start --port=$PORT",
    "generate": "~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"**/*.{vue,css}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:style"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1637333559.35dbd53",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^7.0.4",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-tailwind": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-mugen-scroll": "^0.2.6",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-tailwind": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@namics/stylelint-bem": "^7.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^10.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.5",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-html": "^1.4.1",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^10.1.10",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.4",
    "stylelint": "^14.9.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^26.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-vue": "^1.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-tailwindcss": "^0.0.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Nuxt.config.js

```
const POLYFILL_FEATURES = [ // @see https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/
  'default',
  'es2015',
  'es2016',
  'es2017',
  'es2018',
  'es2019',
  'es5',
  'es6',
  'IntersectionObserver', // @see https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#prefetchlinks
  'window.scroll'
]

export default {
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080
  },
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Rails 7 Nuxt Template',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Rails 7 Nuxt Template' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: `https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=${POLYFILL_FEATURES.join('%2C')}`, body: true }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-tailwind.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/errors.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/axios.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollPosition.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollTo.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: [
    { path: '~/components/AdminBackend', prefix: 'Admin' },
    { path: '~/components/Frontend', prefix: 'F' }
  ],

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    // https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    // https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue
    'portal-vue/nuxt',
    // https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue
    'portal-vue/nuxt'
  ],

  content: {
    // intentionally blank
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true
        },
        user: {
          autoFetch: false,
          property: 'user'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/auth/sign_in',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/auth/sign_out',
            method: 'delete',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/auth/user',
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/dashboard/'
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/auth/auth-i18n.js']
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    headers: {
      common: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    }
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.RAILS_API_ENDPOINT,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }
    },
    '/rails/': {
      target: process.env.RAILS_ENDPOINT
    }
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    directUploadsEndpoint: `${process.env.RAILS_ENDPOINT}/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads`
  },

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common' // required for vue runtime compiler
    },
    html: {
      minify: {
        decodeEntities: false // @see nuxt-protected-mailto
      }
    },
    postcss: {
      // Add plugin names as key and arguments as value
      // Install them before as dependencies with npm or yarn
      plugins: {
        // Disable a plugin by passing false as value
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        autoprefixer: {}
      }
    },
    transpile: [
      '@rails/activestorage',
      'defu'
    ]
  },

  tailwindcss: {
    cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css'
  },

  extend (config, ctx) {
    // Run ESLint on save
    if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const screens = require('./tailwind-breakpoints.config.js')
module.exports = {
  // purge: {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{vue,js}',
    './content/**/*.md',
    './layouts/**/*.vue',
    './pages/**/*.vue',
    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}'
  ],
  // },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    screens,
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blue: {
          font: '#335DB0',
          button: '#335DB0'
        },
        grey: {
          accent: '#D9D9D9',
          bg: '#F5F5F5',
          profile_pic: '#757575'
        },
        red: {
          inactive: '#E25151'
        },
        green: {
          active: '#91E251'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    function ({ addBase, theme }) {
      const screens = theme('screens', {})
      const breakpoints = Object.keys(screens)

      addBase({
        ':root': {
          '--current-breakpoint': 0
        },
        ...breakpoints.reduce((acc, current) => {
          acc[`@media (min-width: ${screens[current]})`] = {
            ':root': {
              '--current-breakpoint': screens[current]
            }
          }
          return acc
        }, {})
      })
    }
  ]
}
```

If someone knows what I am doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: Did you followed the whole guide? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs#2

Answer (score 0):

In `nuxt.config.js` in the `build property` I have renamed `postcss` by `postcssOptions` and added

```
extractCSS: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: 'styles',
            test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

`nuxt.config.js` now looks like this

```
const POLYFILL_FEATURES = [ // @see https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/
  'default',
  'es2015',
  'es2016',
  'es2017',
  'es2018',
  'es2019',
  'es5',
  'es6',
  'IntersectionObserver', // @see https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#prefetchlinks
  'window.scroll'
]

export default {
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080
  },
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Rails 7 Nuxt Template',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Rails 7 Nuxt Template' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: `https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=${POLYFILL_FEATURES.join('%2C')}`, body: true }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-tailwind.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/errors.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/axios.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollPosition.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollTo.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: [
    { path: '~/components/AdminBackend', prefix: 'Admin' },
    { path: '~/components/Frontend', prefix: 'F' }
  ],

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    // https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    // https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue
    'portal-vue/nuxt'
  ],

  content: {
    // intentionally blank
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true
        },
        user: {
          autoFetch: false,
          property: 'user'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/auth/sign_in',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/auth/sign_out',
            method: 'delete',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/auth/user',
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/dashboard/'
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/auth/auth-i18n.js']
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    headers: {
      common: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    }
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.RAILS_API_ENDPOINT,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }
    },
    '/rails/': {
      target: process.env.RAILS_ENDPOINT
    }
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    directUploadsEndpoint: `${process.env.RAILS_ENDPOINT}/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads`
  },

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common' // required for vue runtime compiler
    },
    html: {
      minify: {
        decodeEntities: false // @see nuxt-protected-mailto
      }
    },

    extractCSS: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: 'styles',
            test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    postcssOptions: {
      // Add plugin names as key and arguments as value
      // Install them before as dependencies with npm or yarn
      plugins: {
        // Disable a plugin by passing false as value
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        autoprefixer: {}
      }
    },
    transpile: [
      '@rails/activestorage',
      'defu'
    ]
  },

  extend (config, ctx) {
    // Run ESLint on save
    if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```